# How communicate between raspberry Pi running win 10 IOT and arduino?

Tags: uwp, arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno, windows-10-iot-core

I'm Creating UI with XAML for my Present/Absent device. since r305 or other fingerprint sensors dosen't have a lib in C#, I'm trying to use an arduino Uno in between in order to use Adafruit's Lib for Fingerprint sensors.

I simply can't send data (strings or even simple numbers) to RPi correctly. either it wont show the real number (its shows 255 or 0/1). I've Tried connecting it with USB, UART and (My biggest hope) I2C, but None of them works or do the job correctly. I can connect 2 device togather using ethernet, but I need something more sufficient.

**PLEASE**, don't give me Links to other pages (I'm sick of Remote-Arduino beacuse it wont find my device while I'm giving it everything right). I've been searching the web for about 6 month.. there is nothing new on how to connect these 2

I mean really.. nobody has a sample of this? something that would send Strings or numbers to RPi Win10 IOT and back? I'm willing to use UART or I2C.

I can't give you any sample.. I've used so many samples and edited lots of thinks that I don't know which one you need to see. but please let me know if you need it.

Comment: Do you still need help? Have plenty of examples using i2c to communicate between winiot and arduino (or any device which can join i2c bus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R305 module supports UART/USB1.1 interface,you can connect the module with Raspberry Pi with the interface.
If you choose UART interface,you can connect the module with Raspberry Pi like following map. Windows IoT Core support Serial UART communication.
[image]
You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART).In this sample,it also shows how to use USB-to-TTL adapter with Silicon Labs chipsets to communicate with the module.
But you need to implement the communication protocol which indicated in the datasheet.

Comment: you made my situation a little bit less complicated but, R305  has any lib in c#? I mean after I connected the module successfully, how should I read the fingerprints, enroll them, etc...? thats why I'm using arduino, just to use adafruits libs for r305

Comment: After you connected the module to Raspberry Pi with UART/USB, you can read the data from fingerprint module via Serial Port communication.The sample in my reply contains C# implement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have code sample for windows 10, but I do have for linux, does your project forces you to use Windows?? there is no chance to switch to linux?. I could guide you in the process to interface an i2c sensor using the rpi bus, but with linux.

I could find samples on the microsoft site, take a look, https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/IoT-I2C

And in this blog post, I document a method that I used to interface a 12c sensor and creating a library for linux and python: https://altax.net/blog/pyircamera/

Good luck!

Comment: thanks @aldux for your answer. actually I'm using Windows because of the GUI.. I have a 4inch touch display and have no idea how to make a graphical UI in python.

Comment: you can do a simple and very quick GUI using tkinter, its actually pretty easy! https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter